# How to fix Capybara/Cucumber running outdated code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I'm testing a feature using Cucumber and Capybara (with poltergeist/phantomjs). The problem is that changes that I make to my code are not being reflected in the tests. My tests are failing because I changed the name of a link, if I take a screenshot of the page on the test I can see that it still shows the old link, but if I navigate to the page on my browser, it shows the correct one. I have been trying to solve this since yesterday with no luck. I don't even know which code would be relevant to paste here, has anyone had this problem or has any idea of what this could be?

Thank you!

---

### UPDATE

I was able to fix this by running `rails generate cucumber:install` again. Doing this updated the page on the test. But then I modified the page again and once more it's outdated on the test, running the `cucumber:install` command is not helping anymore either.

Comment: I would suspect the change you made is to different code than your test is accessing. Do you have that same link in two different places in your codebase?

Comment: @sevenseacat No, I'm pretty sure I'm changing the page that my test is accessing, I tried changing many things in the page and neither of them are updated on the test.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using guard for auto tests? try

```
spring stop
```

it will restart [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) preloader. Sometimes it fails to update test code/application code

Answer (score 0):

You should run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=test` and that will regenerate the code that capybara will run.